# sharepoint 2010 page with page layout asking for user credentials

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

i have a sharepoint 2010 site which has  anonymous access, the pages without layouts has no issues.

the pages which are using page layouts are prompting for user credentials.

Please advise me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your layouts are checked-in and published along with its all referred css and script files. Also, the layout should not contain any webpart or control which require elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the page layouts does not have any permissions on them? Or: are you sure that the page layouts have anonymous permissions?